# webcam not opening in webrtc with react.js

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

```
    import React from 'react';

    class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.status = {
        
            }
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

            document.getElementById("call").onclick = async () => {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});
            document.getElementById("video").srcObject = stream;
            for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
                pc.addTrack(track, stream);
            }
            };

            pc.ontrack = ({streams}) => document.getElementById("video").srcObject = streams[0];
            pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => console.log(pc.iceConnectionState);
            pc.onicecandidate = ({candidate}) => sc.send({candidate});
            pc.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
            await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer());
            sc.send({sdp: pc.localDescription});
            }

            const sc = new window.localSocket(); // localStorage signaling hack
            sc.onmessage = async ({data: {sdp, candidate}}) => {
            if (sdp) {
                await pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp);
                if (sdp.type == "offer") {
                await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createAnswer());
                sc.send({sdp: pc.localDescription});
                }
            } else if (candidate) await pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            }
        

    }

        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <video id="video" height="120" width="160" autoplay>

                    </video>
                    <br/>
                    <button id="call">Call!</button>
                    <br/>
                    <div id="div"></div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Test;
```

Here is my code to open webcam.
I am following https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/2yLakm60 link an doing in react.js

https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/2yLakm60

But, my code is not working.

Webcam light is coming but camera is not showing.

Please take a look hOw can i solve this.

Comment: what browser are u using? and where are u testing webrtc?

Comment: It's working on my android device. However, you should add a check for secure context before getting mediaDevices